# Anonymous function in R using sparklyr spark_apply

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use the spark_apply() function from library(sparklyr) I am using the spark_apply() function because the sparklyr package does not support using subsets. I am a bit lost about where I need to include the function(e) within the following dplyr syntax.

Here is the original syntax I am trying to adapt with an anonymous function (I'm not 100% this is the term)

```
match_cat3 <- match_cat2 %>%
          group_by(VarE, VarF) %>%
          mutate(Var_G = if(any(Var_C ==1)) ((VarG - VarG[Var_C == 
1])/(Var_G + Var_G[Var_C == 1])/2) else NA)
```

Here is my attempt at using the spark_apply() function with the mutate equation from above. I would love some help with how to use the function(e) and where the e goes within the syntax. I don't have any experience using a function within another function like this.

```
match_cat3 <- spark_apply(
                    function(e)
                    match_cat2 %>%
                    group_by(e$VarE, e$VarF) %>%
                    mutate(e$Var_G = if(any(e$Var_C ==1)) ((e$VarG - 
e$VarG[e$Var_C == 1])/(e$Var_G + e$Var_G[e$Var_C == 1])/2) else NA, e)
)
```

```
This gives me an out of bounds error.

I was basing the syntax off of the following block from the spark_apply() documentation.

```
trees_tbl %>%
spark_apply(
function(e) data.frame(2.54 * e$Girth, e),
names = c("Girth(cm)", colnames(trees)))
```

Thanks!

Comment: The anon-func has a few things that confuse me. First, what does `e` look like? Is it a frame full of data, or a frame full of things that you then apply to different data (`match_cat2`)? Second, you cannot assign `e$Var_G` on the left side in `mutate`, you will need some more magic to get that logic to work. Third, nothing in your `mutate` uses anything in `match_cat2`, everything is based (incorrectly?) on `e`. (Perhaps just replace `match_cat2` with `e` and remove all remaining `e$`.)

Comment: Yes the e is a frame full of data. The match_cat2 is the same data frame that I am trying to manipulate. I'll give the replacing match_cat2 with e a try! Do you happen to have any resources you would recommend me look at for how to understand how anon-funcs works?

Comment: It's just like a named function, nothing special: you could always do `myfunc <- function(e) { ... }`, then `spark_apply(myfunc)`. You should be very careful when accessing data stored outside of what is explicitly given to a function. A good practice is to be explicit with what you pass to the function and what the function can use internally. As an example, it's legal to do `x <- 1; sapply(2:4, function(i) i+x)`, but that's a scope breach. Many `*apply`s allow arguments, so `x <- 1; sapply(2:4, function(i,a) i+a, a=x)` does it without scope breach, as `a` is known and available internally.

Comment: Hey @r2evans thanks so much for your help. I'm still a bit lost when writing a function.

I wrote the following function but its still out of bounds, any help would be awesome

     `trans <- function(e) {
                   e %>%
                    group_by(VarE, VarF) %>%
                    mutate(Var_G = if(any(Var_C ==1)) ((VarG - 
    VarG[Var_C == 1])/(Var_G + Var_G[Var_C == 1])/2) else 
    NA,)
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be having trouble writing a `sparklyr::spark_apply()` function. The template that might be more useful for you starts with your Spark DataFrame.

```
##### data_sf is a Spark DataFrame that will be sent to all workers for R
data_sf <- sparklyr::copy_to(sc, iris, overwrite = TRUE)

data2_sf <- sparklyr::spark_apply(
  x = data_sf,
  f = function(x) {  ##### data_sf will be the argument passed to this x parameter
    x$Petal_Length <- x$Petal_Length + 10 ##### data_sf will now be converted to an R object used here (Spark doesn't like `Petal.Length` so automatically changes column names)
    return(x)
  })
```

In your case:

- you're missing the `x` argument, the first in `sparklyr::spark_apply()`
- you're bringing in external stuff (`match_cat2`) through the `e` argument of your anonymous function but improperly putting it inside the definition of the function as well
- you're missing brackets around your multiline expression and so you aren't defining a function
- you're trying to use `dplyr` (and `magrittr`) with wrong syntax--you can refer to variables like `group_by(VarE)` not `group_by(e$VarE)`

> Functions are defined as `function(data, context) {}` where you can provide arbitrary code within the `{}`. [Chapter 11.7 Functions](https://therinspark.com/distributed.html#functions)

- you're trying to do some conditional stuff in your if else (you could also use the `ifelse()` function here) but I'm not sure what your intent is

```
##### Rewritten, maybe helpful?
match_cat3 <- spark_apply(
  x = match_cat2, ##### the Spark DataFrame you give to spark_apply()
                    function(e) { ##### the opening bracket
                    e %>% ##### the function's argument, NOT `match_cat2 %>%`
                    group_by(VarE, VarF) %>% ##### remove `e$`
                    mutate(Var_G = something_good) ##### not sure of your intent here
})
```